# What classloader does Play use when compiling classes with the JDT compiler?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm trying to write a Play plugin that adds jar files to the Play classpath at runtime. When `onLoad` is called it needs to load up a set of jars so that the JDT compiler can use them to resolve dependencies in the application classes. These jar files are not in the standard `lib/` directory and therefore are not loaded up into the system classpath when Play starts.

Actually loading the jar file is not a problem, I'm going to specify each jar file I need as a URL and then pass those to an instance of `URLClassLoader`.

After a lot of research I've made the assumption that the classloader that Play uses is in `Play.classloader` and my initial plan was to create my own classloader that extends `Play.ApplicationClassloader`. This classloader would use an instance of URLClassLoader to find classes before delegating to the standard functionality in `Play.ApplicationClassloader`. I was then going to replace the Play classloader with my new instance:

```
Play.classloader = new MyExtensionClassLoader();
```

The problem I'm hitting is that the JDT compiler doesn't seem to use the `Play.classloader` instance to load it's classes.

So I have two questions:

What classpath is the JDT compiler actually using if it's not using the `Play.classloader` instance?

More generally, does anyone have any suggestions how I load a jar into Play at runtime so that the JDT compiler can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that will work.

Play has its own classloader which first checks if a class is "a managed play application class" (the one that gets compiled with the JDT compiler runtime), then it fallbacks to the parent classloader which is the default jvm-one..

So all playframework-core classes and other libraries like Hibernate-classes are all loaded as regular classes from the default jvm-classloader.

I hope you understand me :)

-morten

Comment: After a little more investigation: The magic happens in 'private NameEnvironmentAnswer findType(final String name)' in ApplicationCompiler which loads the class's bytes via 'Play.classloader.getClassDefinition(name)' which inturn uses getResourceAsStream(name) (which is a default classloader method).

Comment: That does make sense. As mentioned, I have replaced the instance of `ApplicationClassloader` which is in `Play.classloader` with my own instance. I know that it gets called for application classes but it seems that the JDT compiler doesn't use that class loader.

Comment: I had assumed that by replacing the `Play.classloader` that `ApplicationCompiler.compile() ... findType()` would be using my new instance to load classes. This isn't the case though.

I had hoped to hook into `findType()` in this section: '// So it's a standard class
    byte[] bytes = Play.classloader.getClassDefinition(name);' which is on line 184-185 of `ApplicationCompiler`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you cannot modify which java.lang.Classloader is parent-classloader for ApplicationClassloader.

If you look in the constructor you see that it always picks the classloader which ApplicationClassloader.class was loaded from.

If you could send parent-classloader as param to ApplicationClassloader's constructor, then you could do this:

create new ClassloaderA extends java.lang.Classloader with parent-classloader as JVM-default. Then in ClassloaderA, override findClass and getResourceAsStream to look in your jar-files before looking in parent. then you could give Play.classloader a new instance of ApplicationClassloader with an instance of ClassloaderA as its parent classloader.

I think this will make the Classloader-hirarchy correct..

Comment: Couple of questions. 1/ How do I get the JVM-default classloader? (`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`?) 2/ How do I create the new instance of `ApplicationClassloader` so that `ClassloaderA` is it's parent classloader?

Comment: In the interests of answering my own question because doing anything else is just being plain lazy, 1/ How do I get the JVM default classloader ..... it can be defined in the system property "java.system.class.loader" so on startup you can specify -D java.system.class.loader=MyCustomClassLoader

Comment: When I say 'default classloader' I mean the initial classloader which is loading the first classes (or all classes) before we start trixing it. All classobjects have ref to the classloader instance it was loaded from, so Integer.class.getClassloader() returns the classloader-instance I am talking about